# Unable to get all the posts or feeds using Facebook Graph API's like me/feed or me/posts

Tags: facebook, api

I am using Facebook Graph api in salesforce to make a facebook widget. Now once I achieved to get an valid access token using Oauth , I am making an get request to get all the feed and posts from my facebook wall, but the issue is I am getting only feed or posts those I have posted on my wall myself or been tagged in.
But if someone from my friend side has posted something (lets say my friend Mark has uploaded a photo of himself where I haven't tagged), then its not coming in the API feed or posts request , unless Mark tagged me in it, although its been showing to me on my home wall through facebook account login. So is there a way to get all the feeds and posts of my home wall irrespective of the fact that I have been tagged or shared in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is pratically no longer possible to get `/me/home`, which is what you are trying to do. The results you describe if you're using `/me/feed` seem to be correct.

The reason is that FB doesn't grant the necessary `read_stream` permission anymore.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> The GET /v2.4/{user_id}/home, GET /v2.4/{user_id}/inbox, and GET /v2.4/{user_id}/notifications operations as well as read_stream, read_mailbox, and manage_notifications permissions are deprecated in v2.4.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But please let me know the alternative of me/home as I want to fetch my complete wall(timeline) , whereas from me/feed I am getting posts or feeds from timeline in which I am tagged in or shared with me only.

Comment: There is no alternative way